# How can i create a link to an external site using a href in react.js? (using react bootstrap)

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, href, external

```
<NavItem
    className="navbar"
    target="_blank"
    role="link"
    href="https://www.google.com"
>
   <Fa name="question-circle-o" title="Help" />
</NavItem>
```

I am using react bootstrap to create a navbar. On this particular part of the navbar, I am using font awesome to create a button, that when clicked will open up a new tab to google. However, when I use the above code and click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to add [`as` prop](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/navs/#nav-item-props) to make it act like a specific HTML element**

So:

```
<NavItem
    className="navbar"
    target="_blank"
    role="link"
    href="https://www.google.com"
    as="a" //<-- ADD HERE
>
   <Fa name="question-circle-o" title="Help" />
</NavItem>
```

Comment: I tried to use the as prop, but unfortunately I am still experiencing the same issue